# TryCatch Decorator not catching errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Following tryCatch decorator is unable to catch the error.

```
const TryCatchWrapper = (target, key, descriptor) => {
  const fn = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = (...args) => {
    try {
      fn.apply(this, args);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Entered Catch----->');
      const [,, next] = args;
      next(error);
    }
  };
};
```

Trying to use in the following class-

```
class CustomerDetails {

  @TryCatchWrapper
  async getCustomerSummary(req, res, next) {
      throw new Error('Whoops!!!');
  }
}
```

**Problem:-**
*'Entered Catch----->'* never gets printed.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `getCustomerSummary` is an `async` function. An `async` function *never* throws; instead, it returns a promise that gets rejected. (*Inside* an `async` function, when you use `try`/`catch` around `await`, that gets turned into promise rejection handling. But in a non-`async` function calling an `async` function, that sugar isn't applied.)

You'll need to modify the decorator to look at the return value of the function and, if it's a promise, handle promise rejections.

Comment: Thank you. Atleast it gave me a direction.

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is nothing wrong with your approach. You just forgot to `await` for results from `fn.apply` and set the `descriptor.value` as `async` function.
See the example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dycwcg

```
const TryCatchWrapper = (target, key, descriptor) => {
  const fn = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = async (...args) => {
    try {
      await fn.apply(this, args);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Entered Catch----->');
      const [,, next] = args;
      next(error);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you use `this` in `fn.apply`?

Comment: If I remember properly, "this" is actually CustomerDetails instance scope. That way "this" inside instance method is bind to actual customerDetails instance